# Is it possible to convert Blurhash string to CSS gradients?

Tags: css, css-gradients

I'm currently interested in [Blurhash](https://blurha.sh), which can be used as user-friendly placeholder for image loading, to convert the given hash into a set of CSS gradient background, so I may use it as a placeholder like:

```css
{
  background: radial-gradient(...) linear-gradient(...); /* converted Blurhash representation */
  background: url('/path/to/image.jpg');
}
```

or:

```css
<img src="/path/to/image.png" style="background: radial-gradient(...) linear-gradient(...);">
```

I know that it is currently possible to use these hashes on web, [and there's also an official TypeScript implementation](https://github.com/woltapp/blurhash/tree/master/TypeScript), but the library only returns the decoded hash in terms of pixels (or HTML `<canvas>` data).

Are there any library that can convert these data into CSS gradient instructions?

Comment: What do Blurhash values look like? It's a long string? a large number? A guid? More detail about the nature of a Blurhash value would be helpful.

Comment: See https://blurha.sh, a hash of characters that defines the gradient points, colors, and intensity that defines the blurred representation of the actual image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking into this myself recently. Here are some of the solutions I found:

- [`@unpic/placeholder`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@unpic/placeholder) - a JS library which offers a `blurhashToCssGradients` function which turns a BlurHash into a series of `radial-gradient()` declarations.
- https://github.com/aredridel/blurhash-to-css - a PHP library which offers way to turn a BlurHash into a combination `linear-gradient` declarations, `transform`, and `blur`
- [`blurhash-gradients`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blurhash-gradients) - another JS library, uses gradients, `clip-path`, `filter`, and `box-shadow`. Very new, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/LorisSigrist/blurhash-gradients) it seems to have at least some documentation.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect it to see a working solution for both Laravel and React, too. Thanks!